# how to resolve MSTest.TestAdapter build errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, mstest

The following build errors occur when trying to build a solution file for the first time. The solution worked for the previous developer but he is no longer around. This is my first time using test projects.

Windows Server 2016
Visual Studio 15.7.6 (recently updated from 15.6)
if i follow the directory path the error message uses to find the file it goes south at \build\ as there is no _common directory under it.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy the file "D:\SearchOptimization\Projects\MQReaderService_KLRParse\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll" because it was not found.  ParserUnitTests
Error       Could not copy the file "D:\SearchOptimization\Projects\MQReaderService_KLRParse\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll" because it was not found.    ParserUnitTests
Error       Could not copy the file "D:\SearchOptimization\Projects\MQReaderService_KLRParse\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.3.2\build_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" because it was not found.  ParserUnitTests

Comment: Did you tried reinstalling the package from nuget server?, if not try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mahesh's lead I navigated:
Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Updates tab -> MSTest.TestAdaptor

I saw that there was an update available so I installed it, restarted VS, cleaned the solution, built the solution.

The build errors are gone!

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).